# Password reset screens appearing while inactive; was I hacked?

Tags: updates, malware

I put down my Samsung Galaxy S7 phone after making a phone call, and then noticed that the settings appeared on screen, and things like "reset password" were being clicked and text was being entered into password fields for my Samsung and Gmail account.

After unsuccessfully trying for a few seconds to get this to stop, I completely switched off the phone. I have since checked my accounts from another device, and nothing (visible to me) seems to have happened there.

I had been warned about an OS update yesterday, but stupidly clicked to install it later. Now I'm wondering whether there's anything in particular I should do when (or before) I switch on my phone again. Does all this sound like the symptoms of the Android vulnerability that has been in the news this month? And if I get the update installed, will this also check whether the vulnerability has been exploited?

Comment: The possibility of being hacked can't be rejected but hackers usually aren't interested in showing you what they are doing to your data until the hack isn't complete. Just to point out a secondary thing, sometimes phone screen gets slightly wet during lengthy phone calls due to sweat/oil on skin. As soon as call ends or proximity sensor detects that phone is away from body, wetness on capacitive touch screen simulates some random touches.

Comment: @IrfanLatif That is indeed a possibility. I was so spooked to see my phone do things on its own that I may have misjudged what was going on.